# Range exclusive of boundaries in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a range array like:

```
range_array = [4830..5520, 2000..2700, 600..1335, 3660..4170]
```

And I check for range like:

```
range_array.map{|a| a.include?(3660)}.any? # Gives true as the boundary matches 3660.
```

I want to check for range excluding boundaries. I tried `between?`, but the problem is same.

How do I achieve it with less code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also check the boundaries using `first` and `last`:

```
range_array.map{|a| a.include?(3660) && a.first != 3660 && a.last != 3660}.any?
```

Comment: I did it slightly different: `range_array.map{|a| a.include?(3660) && [a.first, a.last].exclude?(3660)}.any?`

Comment: Wouldn't `range_array.map{|a| a.first < 3660 && a.last > 3660}.any?` be simpler?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for the *ending values* out of the box: use `Range` with [`exclude_end?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html#method-i-exclude_end-3F) set to `false` (denoted by triple dot, e.g. `1...5`.)

To exclude both beginning and end value, one should explicitly check for the values:

```
range_array = [3660...4170]
range_array.map do |range|
  (range.begin.succ...range.end) === 3660
end.any?
```

Comment: Perhaps we could use a method `Range#exclusive_cover?`: `class Range; def exclusive_cover?(other); self.begin < other && self.end > other; end; end`. Then `(1.1..3.4).exclusive_cover?(3.4) #=> false`, `(1.1..3.4).exclusive_cover?(3.3999) #=> true`.

Answer (score 2):

What about?

```
range_array = [4830..5520, 2000..2700, 600..1335, 3660..4170]
range_array.any? do |range| 
   (range.begin.next...range.end).cover?(3660)
end
#=> false
```

Comment: `to_a` would be surprised by e. g. `0..Float::INFINITY` range.

Comment: @mudasobwa 
by the way, `(0..Float::INFINITY).begin.succ...(0..Float::INFINITY).end
 => 1...Infinity`

Comment: @mudasobwa in this way my method will be longer but rather :)

Comment: Not sure I understood this comment. Your `to_a` runs into an infinite loop on `Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: This is relatively inefficient as `arr.include?(3660)` (where `arr = a.to_a[1..-2]`) steps through every element in `arr` until it finds a match or concludes there is not one. By constrast, `3660 > a.begin && 3660 < a.end`, or `(a.begin-1..a.end-2).cover?(a)` only compares end points. Note that using `a` as the block variable may suggest to some readers that it holds an array. Better to use something like `r`, `range` or `rng`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your additions!

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you also, really it was not the best idea, use - `to_a`

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Ranges simply don't support the definition of a range excluding start and end (maybe there should be a four-dot syntax??). So it would be better to manage these values as an array of arrays, or create your own class.

So to answer the question with minimal code, we don't need any range methods; a simple two-part condition will suffice:

```
range_array.map{|a| a.first < 3660 && a.last > 3660}.any?
```

(Thanks to comment by @Cary Swoveland)

Answer (score 0):

I got a way, eg:

```
range = (1..10)
range.reject.with_index{|a, i| [0, range.to_a.length - 1].include?(i)}
```

gives `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Oops, seems **msergeant's** answer is better.